# Jdk update 121 URLClassloader change

Tags: java, urlclassloader, java-8

In Java 121 release notes I could see that they mention that the URLClassloader will throw ClassNotFoundException instead of a SecurityException.  While looking at the code,  I could not see any methods being modified to throw this new exception.  Can someone please explain what is going on here???

Thanks,

Amar

Comment: can you add a link to the diff to your post?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a diff,  I just searched for both these exception so and they showed exactly the same match, therefore the question

Comment: Plus the associated ticket is also not public,  therefore no chance of seeing what happened there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the release notes (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u121-relnotes-3315208.html) there is a new system property (`jdk.net.URLClassPath.disableRestrictedPermissions`) that can be used to disable this new feature.

Googling for `disableRestrictedPermissions` found the following changeset that implements the URLClassloader change:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/rev/dfa1648415a4